# codeigniter delete row from table

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i need same help from u all,
i have a code to delete rocord from table but it`s not working. my same one know.

this is my code

=> view

```
           <table class="table table-striped">
                <th class="success">NO</th>
                <th class="success">TANGGAL</th>
                <th class="success">JUDUL</th>
                <th class="success">AKSI</th>

                <?php 
                    $count = 1;
                    foreach($hasil AS $row){    
                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td width="30px"><?=$count++;?></td>
                    <td width="110px"><?= $row['tanggal']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $row['judul']; ?></td>
                    <td width="190px">
                        <a href="<?=base_url('admin/headline/edit_form/'.$row['id_headline']);?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                        <a href="<?=base_url('admin/headline/hapus/'.$row['id_headline']);?>" class="btn btn-warning">Hapus</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php } ?>                  
            </table>
```

=> routes

```
$route['admin/headline/hapus']                  = 'admin/amor_con_headline/hapus';
```

=> controler

```
public function hapus($id){
  $this->load->model("admin_model/amor_model_headline");
  $this->amor_model_headline->hapus_headline($id);
  redirect('admin/dashboard');
}
```

=> model

```
function hapus_headline($id){
    $this->db->where('id_headline',$id);
    $this->db->DELETE('a_headline');
}
```

it's not work.

=> **EDIT** 
it`s was solved by me. 
i add this in my routes

```
$route['admin/headline/hapus/(:any)']           = 'admin/amor_con_headline/hapus/$1';
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: not delete a record in database

Answer (score 0):

Try

MODEL

```
function hapus_headline($id){
    $this->db->delete('table_name', array('column_name' => $id));
}
```

Or

```
function hapus_headline($id){
    $var = array(
    'column_name' => $id
    );
    $this->db->delete('table_name', $var);
}
```

Comment: thanks for response Sebastian. It's still not working. I got " 404 Page Not Found , The page you requested was not found." when i try your first example code and the secound code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude! using URI

=> Model

```
function hapus_headline(){
    $this->db->where('id_headline', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('a_headline');
}
```

=> controller

```
public function delete()
{
    //product id 
    $id_headline = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->products_model->hapus_headline($id_headline);
    redirect('admin/headline');
}
```

=> view

```
<a href="<?=base_url('admin/headline/hapus/'.$row->id_headline); ?>">Hapus</a>
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time. when i try your code still not working.